# Is any way to get internal html textboxes,buttons names or ids in webview using monkeyrunner in Android

Tags: android, monkeyrunner, androidviewclient

I am using **monkeyrunner dump -VF** option to list all ids and positions too. Now I need all ids and names of controls in webview control. Is it possible to get it using monkeyrunner or how to fetch those controls too.

Comment: @dtmilano Hi Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

First things first, if you are running (as you should) `dump` from **AndroidViewClient >= 4.0.0** you should not use `monkeyrunner` as the interpreter but `python`.

Just:

```
$ ./dump -VF
```

on an operating system that supports shebang, or

```
python dump -VF
```

on a no-so-lucky OS.

`dump` dumps all the android Views and its properties, so unfortunately it's not possible now to dig inside the WebView, perhaps in the future this feature could be added, but it should rely on different techniques than the ones used to obtain the View hierarchy.

Comment: Hi Can I edit code so that I can dig into webview? Is it possible?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `edit code`, but you may need to change WebView itself to provide this kind of information, so it would work only on your firmware. If you think of another way don't hesitate to share it.

Comment: @dtmilano Hi In calabash-android when query on webview it will show all ids Is it possible in AndroidViewClient dump? Is it any way to achieve it using python?